# "message": "Index: 4, Size: 4",SpringBoot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I have these methods to get the data from the database by given date,

**First Query**

```
@Query(nativeQuery=true, value="SELECT COUNT(`user_id`)  FROM `app_user` u LEFT JOIN  `user_etablissement` ue on u.id=ue.user_id WHERE year(u.creatdate_time)= :date GROUP BY `etablissement_id`")
public List<BigInteger> findALLUserBenByyear(@Param("date") String date);
```

**Second QUery**

```
@Query(nativeQuery=true, value="SELECT * FROM `etablissement` WHERE YEAR(creatdate_time)= :date")
public List<Etablissement> findAllEtabname(@Param("date") String date);
```

**Controller method**

```
@GetMapping(value="/etablissementAa/{annee}")
  public  EtablissementDto EtabDTOA(@PathVariable String annee)
  {
    EtablissementDto a = new EtablissementDto();

    
    List<Etablissement> etabs =  etablissementRepository.findAll() ;
    
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < etabs.size(); i++) {
            
            myList.add(etablissementRepository.findAllEtabname(annee).get(i).getEtabName()) ;
            
        }
                    List<BigInteger> UsersNumb =  userRepository.findALLUserBenByyear(annee) ;
        
        List<BigInteger> myList1 = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int j = 0; j <UsersNumb.size(); j++) {
                
                
                myList1.add((BigInteger) userRepository.findALLUserBenByyear(annee).get(j)) ;
            }       
    a.setEtabNamee(myList);
    a.setUsersNumber(myList1);
    return a;
    
      
  }
```

when i excute my method from postman , it shows me this error

```
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "Index: 4, Size: 4",
```

**Full Stack Trace**

```
2021-05-09 17:55:29.913  INFO 16716 --- [nio-8020-exec-1] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2021-05-09 17:55:29.962 ERROR 16716 --- [nio-8020-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4] with root cause

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:659) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at org.club.controller.EtablissementController.EtabDTOA(EtablissementController.java:143) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
```

Comment: Please [edit] the post and add the full stack trace.

Comment: `etabs` is a list of all `Etablissement`. Its size is used in the condition of the 1st `for` loop. In the loop, you get the list of all `Etablissement`s with a certain year. This list is most probably smaller than the list of all `Etablissement`s, hence the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0):

```
myList.add(etablissementRepository.findAllEtabname(annee).get(i).getEtabName()) ;
```

findAllEtabname(annee) will only return elements containing annee. So this will not have the same size as etab. So you can use get(i) here.

You must create a third loop

```
ArrayList<String> etabNames= etablissementRepository.findAllEtabname(annee);
For(String name : etabNames) ....
```

Comment: can you explain me more about the third loop

Answer (score 0):

Change your last loop to this,

```
for (int j = 0; j <UsersNumb.size(); j++) {
                myList1.add((BigInteger) UsersNumb.get(j)) ;
            }
```